# Why is MultiActionController deprecated in Spring 4.3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations, spring-4

In most cases, I'm able to replace `MultiActionController` with an annotated controller just fine. But I have a use-case where I need to map different URLs to DIFFERENT instances of the same controller class, each wired with a different implementation of the same interface. (It's for various find-as-you-type APIs.) I've been using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` for this. Is there any way to do this with an annotated controller? Or do I now have to make separate controller classes for each API? Here's my config with only two `MultiActionController`s shown, although I have more:

```
    <bean name="regionAutocompleteController" class="...ajax.autocomplete.AutocompleteController" autowire="byName">
        <property name="finder" ref="regionFinder"/>
    </bean>
 <bean name="blockAutocompleteController"    class="...ajax.autocomplete.AutocompleteController" autowire="byName">
        <property name="finder" ref="blockFinder"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="atlasAjaxControllerMappings"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">    
        <property name="order" value="4" />
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>             
                <prop key="/findBlock/*">blockAutocompleteController</prop>     
                <prop key="/findRegion/*">regionAutocompleteController</prop>       
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```